# SOLR: Need to replace some words in a text field

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

In SOLR, I need to replace words like:

- `creditcard`
- `CreditCard`
- `creditCARD`

with `creditCard`. I used analyser which is:

```xml
<fieldType>
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But still on querying it doesn't show the replaced text.

I mean CreditCard is not replaced by credtiCard.

**EDIT : syn.txt**

> creditcard,CREDITCARD => creditCard
>
> debitcard => debitCard
>
> personalbanking => personalBanking
>
> paymentcard => paymentCard
>
> currentaccount => currentAccount

Comment: Can you add your `syn.txt` file?

Comment: creditcard,CREDITCARD => creditCard
debitcard => debitCard
personalbanking => personalBanking
paymentcard => paymentCard
currentaccount => currentAccount

Comment: Thx. Can you also add to your post the type of your text. Do you try to use Solr Admin?

Comment: If you are using `ignoreCase`, you don't have to put both `creditcard,CREDITCARD` !

Comment: Tried that as well but no luck. Could you please confirm that these filters affect data as well or these are just for improving queries. In my case CREDITCARD appears CREDITCARD insted of creditCard. :(

Comment: Yes. Can you try with removing `ignoreCase`.

Comment: Appologies if I've misunderstood you, but it sounds like you may be missing how analysis works.  Analysis only transforms the *indexed* terms, it doesn't do anything to the *stored* form of the field.  It's intended to enable more meaningful searching, but it has absolutely no impact on the form of the stored document when you retrieve it from the index.  If your intent is to modify the content of the document, rather than enable search, you should do that before passing it in to Solr.

Comment: @femtoRgon you're right I think I got it wrong and the documentation did everything right to puzzle me. Now I'll happily modify my scala-spark code to do transformation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the word you need to be replaced is contained in certain attribute, lets say 'Att', you could replace it via function in your dataimport.xml file, so you would index the correct value, something like this:

```
<dataConfig>
...
<script>
        <![CDATA[
     function replaceText(row)    {

         var value = row.get('Att');
         if(value.toUpperCase() == 'CREDITCARD'){
              row.put('Att', 'creditCard');
           }

        return row;

       }
     ]]>
</script>
```

And then in the 'entity', add the function as a Transformer:

```
  <entity name="..."
transformer="script:replaceText"
..>
```

Then reindex.

EDITED to simplify